# A problem with nested tables and parallelization

Tags: list-manipulation, parallelization

My code contains the structure

```
Table[....,Table[....,{m1,1,N}],{m2,1,M}]
```

and I would like to use ParallelTable to improve timing. Empirically, I know that ParallelTable[...ParallelTable[...,{}],{}] does not work, so I use

```
ParallelTable[....,Table[....,{m1,1,N}],{m2,1,M}]
```

However, these two codes give different results and I do not know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i = 1;
Table[i++, {j, 1, 4}]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4}

```
h = 1;
ParallelTable[h++, {j, 1, 4}]
```

> {1, 1, 1, 1}

Comment: SetSharedVariable[h], thx